# DE-10 FFMPEG Raw YCbCr 4:2:2 Frame to PNG or Video leads to bad result

Tags: video, ffmpeg, quartus, intel-fpga

So i am trying to record analog video from analog-video in port of the DE10-standard board.

the raw frames are 4:2:2 720x480 hence frame size should be 720*480 * 2 = 691200bytes,however i get 2 more bytes with hex value 0 at the beginning of the frame[two leading bytes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kE17y.png).

ffmpeg complains about wrong buffer size so i removed them.

using `ffmpeg -y -s 720x480 -pix_fmt yuv422p -i input_frame.yuv output_image.png`
the result is way off.

analog video fed to the board has still image (photo taken by phone from TV) [Reference Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upwGE.jpg).
and the result from ffmpeg is [FFMPEG output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXaRx.png).

i used HxD editor and mirrored that single frame many times to create a larger file then used the following command to encode it to MP4 file which give the same result.

`ffmpeg -y -s 720x480 -pix_fmt yuv422p -i dump_video.yuv output_video.mp4`.

i hope someone can help to fix the issue or point me in the right direction as i dont know if the problem is from hardware or from ffmpeg command. Thnx.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your input won't be a planar pixel format `yuv422p`. It will be packed, like `yuyv422`,`yvyu422`, or `uyvy422`.

Comment: It worked using ```uyvy422```, however i got some noise in the middle section outlined in red. [image](https://ibb.co/vdqqY9w)

Comment: That's to do with the tape or the digitization process.